# Passar o valor do id para de uma view para outra - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Tenho a Seguinte view onde tenho uma lista de  artigos cadastrados no banco, ai tenho o botão avaliar que redireciona para uma outra view onde está em uma outra controller, quero passar id do artigo selecionado para outra controller.
Segue imagem do projeto[image: view onde lista os artigos ja cadastrados]

[image: View da avaliação do artigo]

Codigo da action da view avaliar

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AvaliacaoID,NotaArtigo,ComentarioRevisao")] AvaliarArtigo avaliarArtigo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.AvaliarArtigos.Add(avaliarArtigo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(avaliarArtigo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta passar o id do artigo ao clicar em avaliar:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Avaliar", "NomeAction", "NomeController", new { id = item.id})
```

**Action Avaliar**

Na sua action Avaliar você ira receber o `id` do artigo e instanciar um novo objeto do tipo `AvaliarArtigo`. O ideal é que sua classe `AvaliarArtigo` tenho um atributo `ArtigoId`, para saber qual é o artigo que você avaliou, sugiro que fique assim:

```
 public class AvaliarArtigo
 {
     public int AvaliacaoID { get; set; }
     public float NotaArtigo { get; set; }
     public string ComentarioRevisao { get; set; }
     public int ArtigoId { get; set; }
 }
```

e sua Action `Avaliar` ficará assim:

```
 public ActionResult Avaliar(int id)
 {
     avaliarArtigo = new AvaliarArtigo();
     avaliarArtigo.ArtigoId = id;

     return View(avaliarArtigo);
 }
```

**Action que salva a avaliação do artigo**

E na sua action de salvar a avaliação do artigo, basta receber o tipo `AvaliarArtigo` e salva-lo:

```
 public ActionResult Save(AvaliarArtigo avaliarArtigo)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.AvaliarArtigos.Add(avaliarArtigo);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }

      return View(avaliarArtigo);
 }
```